Membership Expiration Dates: How to set the date to be inclusive instead of exclusive?
Current Behavior: "Exclusive" Expiration Dates
When creating or editing a membership, CiviMember automatically sets the Membership Expiration Date based on the Duration specified in the Membership Type if the Membership Expiration Date field is not manually set.
When adding a new membership with a starting date of January 1st...

...with the Student Membership valid for 1 year...

...CiviMember automatically sets the expiration date to December 31st.

Desired Behavior: "Inclusive" Expiration Dates
Using the example above, how can I get CiviMember to automatically set the Membership Expiration Date to January 1, 2025 for a 1-year membership starting on January 1, 2024?
I don't see any configuration option in the UI to enable this.
Should I be looking to code this in a custom extension using hooks?
This would apply to membership types with a Membership Type Duration Unit of either month or year, essentially adding +1 day to the current date calculation.
It could also apply to memberships of day duration, but we don't use those anyway. It wouldn't apply to lifetime memberships.

Appreciate any ideas!

leap years would trip this up but would setting the Duration to 366 days address your issue?

Good idea, Pete. If it was just 1-year durations, that might work. But it won't really be feasible with the variety of membership durations we have: 1 year, 1.5 years, 2 years.

ok. never heard a similar request for a 'year' to be 'a year plus a day'. i assume you will need a custom extension tht will jump in and add one day to a membership. possible civirules could be another route to take

Yeah, 366 days won't work as if they renew on 1st on Jan 2025 they will get end date to 2nd Jan 2025. You will need to add custom code to do this

Thanks for the feedback. I tried CiviRules but there are currently no actions to control the membership expiration date. Looks like a custom extension is the way to go.
